# javascript string replace unicode troubles

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I want to be able to transliterate names into different languages. I'm starting with Armenian.

My html is like this:

```html
    <input type="text" class="name"></input><br>
    <p class="transliterated"></p>
    <button id="button">transliterate!</button>
```

My javascript is like this:

```
var buttonEl = document.getElementById("button");
buttonEl.addEventListener("click", getArmenian);

function getArmenian() {  
  var inputEl = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
  var outputEl = document.getElementsByClassName("transliterated");

  for (var i = 0; i < inputEl.length; i++) {
    var nameEl = inputEl[i].value;   
    var ayb = '&#x561';
    var ben = '&#x562';  
    var nameEl = nameEl.replace(/a/gi, ayb);
    var nameEl = nameEl.replace(/b/gi, ben);
    outputEl[i].innerHTML = nameEl;
  }
}
```

In the above example, I'm picking out the letters a and b, and replacing them with the Armenian characters 'ayb' and 'ben', respectively.

So far so good.

The pickle starts here: I've defined variables for all the letters of the Armenian alphabet the same way I did for 'ayb' and I used replace to replace the respective letter of the English alphabet. This is not a sophisticated transliteration at this point.

The 'x' is problematic, since each code contains an 'x' so I just search and replace the 'x' first, and that mini-problem is solved.

1. But this thing doesn't distinguish between between 'r' and 'R' when searching. How can I fix that? Right now, if I transliterate 'Rob' it gives me '&#x57C + &#x585 + &#x562' which I am happy with, but I didn't *knowingly* program it to recognize the capital letter 'R'.
2. Once I do that, how do I keep this thing from replacing the 'C' in '&#x57C' which is the letter 'ra'?

Comment: remove i from your pattern.  /a/g and /b/g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NULL-POINTER mentioned, it is because if your "i" in the regex pattern. I think that you will have a lot of these "problematic" occurrences doing it via a regex, as multiple letters might have this exact problem. I'd recommend instead using a hash to represent the transliteration. I have made an example that maps a, b, and c to x, y, and z. Of course you'd want to write your own hash, but here's the gist of the idea:

```
var hash = {
    a: "x",
  b: "y",
  c: "z"
};

var str = "abcdddcba";

// first, do a split so each letter is a part of the array
var translate = str.split("")
    // then when you have an array of letters, you can map it to the new values in the hash, and default it to itself if no match is found
  .map((letter) => hash[letter] || letter)
  // next, join all of the letters back together
  .join("");
```

You can check this out on a fiddle I made for you: https://jsfiddle.net/fwkr94Le/

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice so I'm going to have to study your solution. At any rate, 'hash' looks like an object (yes?), and 'translate' is an array, and '.map' and '.join" are methods? This really looks interesting to me because my way is sure to hold all sorts of ugliness

Comment: Close. translate ends up being a string in the end. `hash` is an object that contains how you want to mutate each letter. For example, "a" will change to "x", "b" will change to "y", etc. This is really what you want to change in the fiddle to suit your needs. You may want to read up on map and join, but "translate" will end up being your string after all of the changes defined in "hash" are finished.

Comment: I've played around with this transliteration project for a little bit now and your solution gave me a lot of great ideas. I'm very excited about the split method. To transliterate random names, I downloaded tons of names into excel, concatenated using VBA, then in javascript used split to turn into an array and used Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length) to pick an index randomly